# What is the default setting for ECN (Explicit Congestion Notification)?

Tags: network, macos

According to a few [old articles](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/06/ipv6-ecn-qos-and-other-networking-improvements-in-ios-10-and-macos-sierra/), ECN has been partially enabled around 10.11 El Capitan.

Common instructions to enable ECN fully are

> ```
> sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.ecn_negotiate_in=1
> sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.ecn_initiate_out=1
> ```
>
> To make it persistent, add the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:
>
> ```
> net.inet.tcp.ecn_initiate_out=1
> net.inet.tcp.ecn_negotiate_in=1
> ```

However, I see this:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.ecn_initiate_out=1
net.inet.tcp.ecn_initiate_out: 2 -> 1
```

which says that the default value of `ecn_initiate_out` is **2**, not the expected 0. What does this default value mean? What is the default ECN behavior of macos 10.14 and 10.15?

`ecn_negotiate_in` defaults to 1 in 10.14.

Comment: I have default of **2** for both `ecn_negotiate_in` and `ecn_initiate_out` in 10.14.6.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification#Linux) on Linux (macOS section doesn't mention it) **2** means "*enable ECN when requested by incoming connections, but do not request ECN on outgoing connections*".  May be the same on macOS.

Comment: @lx07 that's because Linux uses one flag with three states. MacOS uses two flags.

Comment: If you look at the source of *tcp_output.c* they changed both from to **0** in El Capitan 10.11.3 ([xnu-3248.30.4](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/bsd/netinet/tcp_output.c.auto.html)) to **2** in 10.11.4 ([xnu-3248.40.184](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.40.184/bsd/netinet/tcp_output.c.auto.html)).  It is the same in current version [xnu-4903.241.1](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4903.241.1/bsd/netinet/tcp_output.c.auto.html).  I can't tell what the **2** means though unfortunately but it fits with what I see from `sysctl`

Comment: @lx07 thanks for the links to source. As near as I can understand it, a value of 2 would mean to enable ECN only for non-cellular interfaces. The wrinkle is that even when "enabled" it still goes through their heuristic code that only enables ECN on 5% of connections. Neither of those conclusions make sense to me, but I'm having a hard enough time finding source for a few methods so I can't follow the logic fully.